# I would like to \includegraphics eps, but also jpeg, png and pdf

Tags: eps, includegraphics, psfrag

I would like to include graphics in one document that I have in the following formats:
eps, jpeg, png, and pdf.

My understanding is that compiling is limited depending on the approach:
latex allows: ps, eps, tiff
pdflatex allows: jpeg, png, pdf

How can I use both eps as well as jpeg, png, and pdf in one document?

Background:
I am using Adobe Illustrator to create tree diagrams and other graphs in EPS format (works very well).
In LaTex, I use \usepackage{psfrag} and \psfrag in order to exchange certain variables in my EPS with certain text. This also works well.

Problem:
However, I also have other graphs and pictures as jpg, pdf etc. As it turned out, compiling the document with latex - which I need for the EPS and the psfrag package - does not include the graphs in jpg, png, or pdf.

I am using TexShop (for Mac, if that makes a difference at all).

Very many thanks!

Matthias

Comment: The way to do it is to convert the eps to pdf outside of LaTeX, and then use the PDF's inside of pdflatex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes note the `psfrag` requirement

Comment: Just to confirm what you mean: 1.) create EPS in Adobe Illustrator 2.) Includegraphics in Latex and exchange the fonts using psfrag 3.) compile as pdf 4.) Include pdf again the actual document using pdflatex ?

Comment: It might be easier to not add any text to the EPS at all. Then convert it to PDF, and use tikz to add stuff on top op it.

Comment: You can go with `XeLaTeX`, it will accepts both EPS and JPG and PDF and PNG format in a same file...

Comment: pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX also accept both EPS and JPG/PNG/PDF graphics. The conversion from EPS to PDF is done automatically, without any packages or settings. If you want to use `psfrag` in pdfLaTeX then you need the `pstool` package or the older `auto-pst-pdf` package. For XeLaTeX you don't need extra packages for `psfrag`.

Comment: EPS was a useful format 20 years ago. Today I see no reason why not to use PDFs. PDFs handle both raster and vector graphics correctly. They are standardized, colour managed and handle metadata. There are even safety issues related to EPS.

Comment: @tanGIS with a PDF you cannot use `psfrag`, with an EPS you can.

Comment: @Marijin: True. But the right to exist of psfrag was that EPS was Illustrator's main format back then. Today it's PDF. psfrag stopped development in 1998! I am happy that Windows 95 is history.

Comment: @daleif Would you provide me a link or some more information on how to use Tikz to add on latex-text on graphics?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks! I see that XeLaTex allows different types of images, but does XeLaTex also allow text overlay on top of an image? So far, my understanding is that only latex allows to use psfrag package.

Comment: @Matt.Shanghai I have tried a few things and it seems I was wrong before, XeLaTeX does _not_ support `psfrag`, with or without extra packages (although it does support `pstricks`). However, pdfLaTeX _does_ support `psfrag`, as I commented earlier (using the `auto-pst-pdf` package) and pdfLaTeX also supports png, jpg, pdf, and 'normal' eps graphics automatically.

Comment: Guys: I actually figured it out. It totally worked with the overpic package. Thanks to everyone anyways!